# Using Google App Engine transaction

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have two tasks (`a`, `b`) those should be performed in transaction in order avoid inconsistency. I may need to perform one of the tasks or both of them together.

In below code `function_a` performs `task a` and `function_b` performs `task b`.

```
@ndb.transactional
def function_a():
    # basic validations
    # read entity of type A
    # make changes to entity
    # write entity
    return

@ndb.transactional
def function_b():
    # basic validations
    # read entity of type B
    # make changes to entity
    # write entity
    return
```

So if I need to perform task a and b together. I can perform as below :-

```
def function_ab():
    function_a()
    function_b()
    return
```

but this implementation will not maintain consistency of `A` and `B` together, so I need to make it transactional too.

```
@ndb.transactional
def function_ab():
    function_a()
    function_b()
    return
```

So, in implementation like this is using transaction multiple times (once on `function_ab` and once for individual `funcion_a` and `function_b`) for the sake of code reusability. If I do not go for code reusability I can do some like below :-

```
@ndb.transactional
def function_ab():
    # basic validations
    # read entity of type A
    # make changes to entity
    # write entity

    # basic validations
    # read entity of type B
    # make changes to entity
    # write entity    
    return
```

I do not know much about how transactions work in app engine, so my question is, Is there any drawback (performance etc.) of using transactions with code reusability over I do not go for code reusability and does the code reusability approach really work?

Answer (score 1):

You can't nest transactions, your transactional `function_ab()` will give an error.

But you can still arrange the code for re-use by ensuring only the top level(s) functions are transactional while the inner ones just check that they are indeed inside a transaction. Maybe something along these lines:

```
def function_a():
    assert ndb.in_transaction()
    return

def function_b():
    assert ndb.in_transaction()
    return

@ndb.transactional
def function_ab(do_a, do_b):
    if do_a:
        function_a()
    if do_b:
        function_b()
```

Your usage pattern is actually textbook fit for using `ndb` async tasklets, even more efficient. Look for the `get_cart_plus_offers()` example in [Tasklets, Parallel Queries, Parallel Yield](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#parallel_queries_yield).

Comment: The nested transactions in app engine is working fine as I tested by writing some code and the get_cart_plus_offers() is for reading data from db not for writing data to db. https://gist.github.com/kumar003vinod/603f883f388413fa626e

Comment: It's possible (I'm not sure) that the nested transactions worked in your case because the 2 functions don't cause conflicts since they operate on different entities, not sure. But that wasn't my case.

Comment: Just replace `get_async()` with assignments plus `put_async()` and you get similar write to db tasklets (more examples in that article). It doesn't really matter if the tasklets do reads or writes, the point is executing them in parallel (which is possible since they operate on different entities). Otherwise they're serialized. At high volume of operations that could make a huge difference in performance.

Comment: So in case where we are using nested transaction for different entities and do not get any error vs the way suggested in answer, where we use only one transaction, is there any performance impacts?

Comment: The performance impact I'm referring to is not related to nesting the transactions (it happens even inside the same transaction) - it comes from using the synchronous DB accesses  which are serialized vs. the async tasklets which can happen in parallel.